# what actually happens by running gluster exporter inside gluster pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus, glusterfs

I created a glusterfs storage.
It automatically created gluster pod.
Now I went inside the pod and I ran gluster exporter there.
My goal was to monitor gluster storage that I created.
Did I achieved my goal?
If not ,what I did then by running gluster exporter inside the gluster pod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems glusterfs dynamic provisioning, so you have already configured heketi component for provisioning glusterfs volumes automatically like below one.

- Hello World application using GlusterFS Dynamic Provisioning

  [ https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes/blob/master/docs/examples/hello_world/README.md ]

Then I think you can monitor easily via heketi REST API.

- Heketi - Get Metrics

  [ https://github.com/heketi/heketi/blob/master/docs/api/api.md#get-metrics ]

Comment: Did I monitored the gluster storage ?

Comment: Maybe yes, if you have installed heketi on your glusterfs pods, if not, you can try it, as a following link.
[ https://github.com/heketi/heketi/blob/master/docs/admin/readme.md ]

Comment: how do we use the apis of heketi..I mean what command should we type for getting heketi metrics

Comment: If you use Prometheus, see this https://github.com/CSCfi/heketi-metrics-exporter/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Usual monitoring tools provide custom monitoring configurations, so you can use it.